# Vlc player is always fullscreen on a specific folder

Tags: vlc

I run windows 8 right now, and when I open a vlc file from this folder, it automatically fills up my entire screen?  When I open a file from another folder, its smaller and how I want it. Also, I have to manually resize vlc each time, and then when I open another file in the same folder, it's back to full screen again. I don't know why this is hapenning in a SPECIFIC folder. How do I make it so that its not fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that your media is a higher resolution in that folder.  VLC automatically shows media at it's full resolution, so I don't think you can do much about this.

Comment: lmfao how did u even find this its 6 months old